# Running gunicorn on https?

Tags: ssl, https, gunicorn

We've got a few Django setups that go through a proxy (Apache and Nginx) that eventually make their way to the actual Django runtime.

We need to have HTTPS end to end even once it's in our network.  We've been revisiting Gunicorn due to its success and performance in our other setups, but needed to test with HTTPS end to end to be consistent.

Our topology is as such:

https://foo.com -> [Public facing proxy] -> (https) -> [internal server https://192...:8001]

How does one configure Gunicorn to listen on HTTPS with a self signed certificate?

Answer (score 142):

Gunicorn now supports SSL, [as of version 17.0](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/0.17.0/news.html).  You can configure it to listen on https like this:

```
$ gunicorn --certfile=server.crt --keyfile=server.key test:app
```

If you were using `--bind` to listen on port 80, remember to change the port to 443 (the default port for HTTPS connections). For example:

```
$ gunicorn --certfile=server.crt --keyfile=server.key --bind 0.0.0.0:443 test:app
```

Comment: Can you point me at the relevant documents for how to do this? I'm deploying on heroku so i'm unsure what my "server.crt" for instance.

Comment: @DrewV If you're deploying on heroku there's no need to support SSL yourself - heroku does it for you.  See [their docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) for help.  You will need to configure gunicorn to honor heroku's secure header configuration.  I use something like this in my config file:

`forwarded_allow_ips = '*'`
and
`secure_scheme_headers = {'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https',}`

Comment: What is the `test:app` part of the end?

Comment: Running this for me returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'uri'`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I added these settings to my `gunicorn_start.bash` file and restarted `supervisor`. Now everything works just fine.

Comment: @GregM how do you know the traffic is secure between all hops public facing <--> application server?

Comment: OMG forgot the port 443!

Answer (score 29):

Massively late reply, but for anyone else coming across this, there's another option using nginx as the "[Public facing proxy]" above.

Configure nginx to handle the incoming SSL traffic on port 443, and then [proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) to gunicorn on an internal port. External traffic is encrypted, and the traffic between nginx and gunicorn isn't exposed anyway. I find this very simple to manage.

Comment: How do you know it isn't exposed?

Comment: Because you bind gunicorn to 127.0.0.1, such that only localhost can access it

Comment: Downside of this is it breaks Django's `build_absolute_uri()` function; Django will see the HTTP protocol and build the URI using that scheme, even if the original request was with HTTPS.

Comment: @robbrit you can set a header to avoid that issue. See the [SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header) docs.

Comment: Given people are still reading this answer - in 2021 I suggest you don't use nginx and instead check out Caddy server

Answer (score 9):

If you're using a gunicorn.config.py or similar gunicorn config file you can add the certificate file and key file.

```
certfile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem'
keyfile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'
```

Config files can be used to initialise settings as env variables and can be helpful if you had lots of settings.
To use config file

- Create a config file by creating a file named
  `gunicorn.config.py`
- Some usual settings would be

  ```
    bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
    workers = 4
    pidfile = 'pidfile'
    errorlog = 'errorlog'
    loglevel = 'info'
    accesslog = 'accesslog'
    access_log_format = '%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
  ```

  and of course

  ```
    certfile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem'
    keyfile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'
  ```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html) and a config file [example](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/examples/example_config.py)

to run gunicorn with these settings

```
    $ gunicorn app:app
```

since

> By default, a file named gunicorn.conf.py will be read from the same directory where gunicorn is being run.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `certfile` and `keyfile` you need to add `ca-certs` as well. Without passing `ca-certs`, I was getting `Trust anchor for certification path not found.` on Android devices.

Sample command:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:443 wsgi:app --workers=8 --access-logfile=/root/app/logs/access.log --error-logfile=/root/app/logs/error.log --certfile=/root/app/certificate.crt --keyfile=/root/app/private.key --ca-certs=/root/app/ca_bundle.crt --daemon
```