# Nginx Reverse proxy not working with Gunicorn over LetsEncrypt SSL connection

Tags: ssl, nginx, gunicorn

I've EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 Server with Python Flask framework running on `Gunicorn`  application server with `Nginx` reverse proxy listening on port 80 & 443. I've added `LetsEncrypt` for the domain using certbot.

The website works fine without ssl. With `LetsEncrypt` ssl configuration on `Nginx` the server fails to load the page. 
My previous `supervisor` and `Nginx` configuration without ssl support is as follows and `Nginx` works with `gunicorn` with no issues.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location /static {
                alias /home/ubuntu/myapp-backend/myapp/static;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

```
[program:myapp]
directory=/home/ubuntu/myapp-backend
command=/home/ubuntu/myapp-backend/venv/bin/gunicorn -w 5 run:app
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp/myapp.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp/myapp.out.log
```

When I change the `Nginx` configuration to include `LetsEncrypt` support while listening on port 80 & 443, the website doesn't show up.. It shows indefinite 301 redirects requests.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/myapp-backend/myapp/static;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

When I load the site `example.com`, it redirects to `https:\\www.example.com`. However the website homepage doesn't load or show any response from server/Nginx. When I login to the server and run `curl -v localhost:8000`, the the gunicorn works fine.

```sh
curl -v localhost:8000
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
< Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< Date: Sat, 28 Sep 2019 14:14:47 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 27911
<
<!doctype html>
...
```

There was earlier Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406805/running-gunicorn-on-https) on `gunicorn` over ssl with [ssl parameters](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#ssl) which can be added to `supervisor` config.
I believe the error must be with on `Nginx` configuration on port 443 or `Gunicorn` `supervisor` config info. If you could have a look, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

**You have too many `server` blocks**

The second block in your configration with SSL, catches connections to `443` and redirects them to the `https://` URL.  Thus causing the infinite loop:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This `301` should only be returned when the user hits the server on port `80`.  That's what the first `server` block in this config file actually does.

Remove this whole block and it should probably work.  You already have the third server block configured to (correctly) catch traffic to `443` and proxy it to gunicorn.

> There was earlier Stackoverflow question on gunicorn over ssl with ssl parameters which can be added to supervisor config. I believe the error must be with on Nginx configuration.

You are terminating SSL at nginx, then proxying to gunicorn in plain HTTP (which is the correct way to operate with nginx involved).  The question you linked there is about adding native SSL support to gunicorn, so that gunicorn terminates SSL.  This would only be required if your internet based users connect directly to the gunicorn server.