# How to encrypt connection with Django server?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django REST framework API and I have a problem - connection with the server is not encrypted. Is there a method to encrypt the server and the connection to it? I use Django for backend and React.js for frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by encryption you mean SSL/TLS

There are 3 places you can do this:

- Load Balancer eg [AWS load balancer](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/configure-elb-ssl-aws/)
- [Dedicated Web Server / Reverse proxy](https://realpython.com/django-nginx-gunicorn/#incorporating-nginx) eg [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)
- Directly in the application process eg [gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406805/running-gunicorn-on-https) / [nodejs](https://hackernoon.com/set-up-ssl-in-nodejs-and-express-using-openssl-f2529eab5bb)

Answer (score 0):

I use gunicorn as server to deploy django-project apps (never use runserver in production!) and gunicorn can encrypt your traffic: [gunicorn-docu](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#ssl)

Example for a simple gunicorn-one-liner-start:

```
gunicorn YOURappNAME.wsgi:application --certfile=server.crt --keyfile=server.key --bind YOURip:YOURport --workers 3 --threads 4 --log-file - --access-logfile - --error-logfile - --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --log-level info -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE --access-logformat '%(h)s %({X-Forwarded-For}i)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"'
```

I use this in a container startscript