# Run local NGINX web app on HTTPS without domain name

Tags: django, nginx, ssl, https

I'm developing a django web app which runs on a gunicorn-nginx local server.

I've followed this [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) guide to setup the web app but I don't understand how to create a ssl certificate and use it without having a domain name.
I've found a lot of guides but none of them specify how to enable HTTPS without a domain and using a local IP.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a self-signed certificate using openssl ([How to generate a self-signed SSL certificate using OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl/10176685#10176685)). But these certificates will not have the security layer provide by CA certificate providers.

Once you have a certificate, then you can run the gunicorn server in HTTPS mode by providing the certificate and the key ([Running gunicorn on https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406805/running-gunicorn-on-https))